# Reload UITableView without reloading header section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableview` with section and index title. When user click on a cell a option view of height 42 gets display in that cell. To display that option I reload the cell. But section header is also getting updated. That gives bizarre animation. How to reload only cell,without getting called for other delegate method like `heightForHeaderInSection` and `viewForHeaderInSection`.

Comment: What code have you written to reload the tableview. And what exactly you want to do. You want to reload only cell or Section?

Comment: use `begin/endupdate` to reload cell

Answer (score 2):

I think you should only update the particular row for indexPath, try the code below

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [tableView endUpdates];

}
```

It might help you.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

> In Swift 2.0 & above

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        tableView.beginUpdates() 
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()

       }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several methods for reloading the tableview.

1. To reload whole section including section's cell.

   `- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation`

**Example:**

```
[tableVIewContent reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

2. To reload single/multiple cells

   `- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray<NSIndexPath > )indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation`

**Example:**

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

3. To reload whole tableview.

   `- (void)reloadData;`

   // reloads everything from scratch. redisplays visible rows. because we only keep info about visible rows, this is cheap. will adjust offset if table shrinks